# Posting data from database at regular time intervals automatically in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have questions stored in my database. I want to regularly post one question on my website from the database at a 24 hr interval automatically. Is there a way I can do that ?

Comment: if you are on some server you can initialize it by setting a crone job. simply write a script for fetching data from database and attach it with the crone job.

Comment: Somehow AJAX can help.

Comment: @RajeshPaul `AJAX` can't help here.

Comment: Please explain to me what you mean by "**post** one question" -  Surely all that is required is to display a question depending on the current or specific date?

Comment: @AlexP there is no date dependency in his problem. Is there???

Comment: @RajeshPaul Yes, when I said 'specific date' I should really have said  a 'time period' (24 hours) - Either way I think the question needs more clarification on what the requirements are of **posting** a question.

Comment: @RajeshPaul .. sorry for lesser details...i want to keep track to of the date and time of posting as well.

Comment: @user2625007 How you you determine which question should be posted?

Comment: User2625007, check my answer. Whatever logic u use doesn't really matter the way I have specified. Check if it is useful. Please comment in my answer whether my answer is useful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with steps:

1. Create normal PHP-script which will post your questions.
2. Schedule your script with standard OS scheduler. It is [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for *nix (Win-versions exist too) or [AT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565) for Windows. To define certain interval - you should read scheduler's manual (for `cron` format is provided [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Format))

Example (cron)

```
0 2 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/insert/script.php
```

-in this case every day at `02:00 AM` cron will try to execute command `/usr/bin/php /path/to/insert/script.php` - i.e. if your `script.php` will extract your question from DB and post it - that will do the stuff.

Comment: I'm still confused by what this `CRON` job will actually be doing - The question is already in the database!

Comment: @AlexP - I've added the sample

Comment: Thanks - I agree it's a valid answer, I just think calling a CRON job is unnecessary in this case as it would mean a update of a stored flag or filter on a date column etc - If this is the case you could just do it dynamically where you display the questions - See my answer for better idea what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by using Cron job . Set time interval and your file script location. It will automatically hit your script on that time interval.

Here is good tutorial : http://docs.phplist.com/SetupCronJob.html

Answer (score 0):

Providing you could create a PHP script to select a different question each time, all you'd need to do would be to set up a cron to run the PHP script every 24 hours. You can find more info on cron [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs/).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into MySQL date functions.

A contrived example would be using [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE publish_date = CURDATE()
```

Storing the `publish_date` will mean you can dynamically load the question when that date arrives.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it correctly is to use cron jobs. You should take a look at the administration panel of your hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script  that will post one question on your website everyday and set a cron job to run that script once a day and you are done.

How to set a cron job , ask you hosting service provider , most of the hosts have  this feature in cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I will shortly outline the two most common solutions. The difficulty rises that PHP is not an always running program, but is a language executed on request and then shutdown on completion.

1. Have some sort of init.php file on your webserver which is being included on every page. That script will check whether the time has passed since last question, and push a new question.
2. On the other hand, you can add a cronjob which will execute your php script pushing the question. This solution is more robust, but requires access to a webserver you might not have.

Answer (score 0):

Create a php file put the code to fetch question form your database 
  then set cronjob to excecute the file on perticular time or also
  you can execute file by including it your login or any other page which 
  lods first by including that php file file so that when first user logs in
  it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

### **Steps**

1. Create a PHP script to **select and post a particular question randomly**.
2. In your main php script **write an AJAX method**(which will load the **PHP script**) which can be called using `setInterval()` using the following syntax-

   `setInterval("AJAX_fun()", 24*3600*1000);`

This statement will call the AJAX function in a periodic interval of 24hrs. For that you **must know AJAX**. I mean what should be the body of the AJAX to load the PHP script that you must have an idea of.

## Another alternative

You can simply reload the page using javascript `setInterval()` function

i.e. `<script>setInterval("window.location.reload()", 24*3600*1000);</script>` and before that you have to **select a question from the database randomly using a PHP logic**.